# CRM 2011 Online Plugin Operation - How to create OrganizationServiceProxy?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I'm trying to create a plugin which creates a task in response to the **create message** for a custom entity.

I've used CrmSvcUtil.exe to generate a custom OrganisationServiceContext, I have a console application test host which successfully uses this to create a task (although using the SDK  serverConnect.GetServerConfiguration() to create the OrganizationServiceProxy).

When i deploy the plugin assembly (sandboxed) to the online instance, the code below blows up with:

> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed

```
// Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
var executionContext = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

// Obtain the organization service reference.
IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(executionContext.UserId);

//Extract the tracing service for use in debugging sandboxed plug-ins.
ITracingService tracingService =
                (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

tracingService.Trace("Buiding");

var organizationUri = new Uri("{theuri}/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");          
var credentials = new ClientCredentials();
credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = NetworkCredential)CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

var organizationServiceProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(organizationUri, null, credentials, null);
organizationServiceProxy.EnableProxyTypes();

var context = new CustomContext(organizationServiceProxy);
```

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `CustomContext` should accept a parameter of type `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService`. Like this (excerpt of a crmsvcutil generated file)

```
/// <summary>
/// Constructor.
/// </summary>
public CrmContext(Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IOrganizationService service) : base(service)
{
}
```

You could (and should) simply generate the connection with help of the plugin context

```
var serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
var service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

using (var crmContext = new CrmContext(service))
{
 ...
}
```

Depending on the value of `{theuri}` you are using, I assume that your request is blocked by the sandbox as it violates its [constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx).

Comment: Thanks this looks good - I'll attempt to make your changes tonight then mark it as the answer. Re the Uri, it's of the form https://{customer}.crm5.dynamics.com which is definitely DNS resolvable and the request itself is anonymous...